# Show SpriteKit score in SwiftUI View

Tags: swiftui, sprite-kit

I am trying to make a ZStack that will overlay the Score from my SpriteKit scene. I got the following code right now, this works showing the code within the actually scene, but I wanna show it in the View

```
import SwiftUI
import SpriteKit

var gameScore = 0

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

let removeLabel = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 0.3), SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.8), SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 0.3)])

override func sceneDidLoad() {
    super.sceneDidLoad()
}
```

Here is the function:

```
// MARK: - Add Score
func addScore(){
    if gameScore < 250 {
        gameScore += 1
        scoreLabel.text = String(format: "%06d", gameScore)
        let possibleScores: Set = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 65, 80, 95, 110, 125, 150, 175, 200, 250]
        
        if possibleScores.contains(gameScore) {
            startNewLevel()
        }
    } else {
        gameScore += 2
        scoreLabel.text = String(format: "%06d", gameScore)
        let possibleScores: Set = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 65, 80, 95, 110, 125, 150, 175, 200, 250]
        
        if possibleScores.contains(gameScore) {
            startNewLevel()
        }
    }
}
```

My View code looks like this:

```
import SwiftUI
import SpriteKit

struct PageTwo: View {

@State var gameScore = 0

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        GameView()
        ZStack {
            Text("Score: \(gameScore)")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It is showing the Score, but not counting it, so maybe someone can tell me where I am going wrong here? This SpriteKit + SwiftUI is new to me and still not quite got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use ObservableObject and a publisher for that, I looked to your codes, there is some code source missing, how ever it is an example for you:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate, ObservableObject {  // <<: Here 1
    
    @Published var gameScore = 0 // <<: Here 2
    
    let removeLabel = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 0.3), SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.8), SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 0.3)])
    
    override func sceneDidLoad() {
        super.sceneDidLoad()
    }
    
    func addScore(){
        if gameScore < 250 {
            gameScore += 1
            
        } else {
            gameScore += 2
            
        }
    }
    
}



struct PageTwo: View {
    
    @StateObject var gameScene: GameScene = GameScene() // <<: Here 3
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("Score: \(gameScene.gameScore)") // <<: Here 4
            .onTapGesture {
                gameScene.addScore()  // <<: Here 5
            }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't change anything, but I think it got me closer. What it is however not doing is counting up the score. It should addScore() every-time an asteroid is destroyed. I know the whole could would be helpful, but it's a lot of code. I am basically rebuilding my game so that the UI is 100% SwiftUI and the logic SpriteKit.

Comment: Have you tried my given codes in answer? it works for me. And it is a way for you, as I said I do not access to your full project and I think it makes no change in my answer either. There is no other way for you, all is in my answer. The way is using ObservableObject.

Comment: I think the last piece of the puzzle is that the .onTapGesture is not right, cause I don't want to addScore() onTapGesture, but rather when the bullet hits the asteroid. The rest of your code works, cause I tested it with onAppear

Comment: Who said that you should use `.onTapGesture` in your project! It is an example to test that we can read/wright to class! why you mixing the test code with your project. no idea! Your issue is not SwiftUI or SpriteKit, you need to learn basic at first! ps: about calling the function of `addScore()` you can call when ever and where ever you want, your last comment shows you have basic problem in coding.

Comment: I know that your example it test code, and that worked. I just gotta figure out how to make it count now with the game logic in swiftui.